# Shortcut in emacs to go to lisp definition directly

Tags: emacs

You can view the help of a lisp function with C-h f, then hit enter on the underlined file name.

Any way to do this with a customized keystroke?

Answer (score 1):

```
(global-set-key "\C-h\C-f" 'find-function-at-point)
```

Comment: If you know the name and want to save a step, you could use `find-function-other-window` or `find-function-other-frame` or `find-function`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways.  The first was suggested by @lawlist in a comment, above.  Wrt the second: this is why Emacs tags were invented: to go immediately to a function definition.

1. `find-function` -- bind it to any key you like.  I bind it to `C-x F` (i.e., `C-x S-f`).
2. `M-.` (command `find-tag`), after building a TAG file -- see `(elisp) Tags`.